# How do I compare dates in Rails?

Tags: ruby, date

I'm trying to compare dates in Rails. I created this method:

```
def compare_dates
    now = Time.now.utc.to_date
    if now == next_appointment_date
      return "Today"
     else
      return "Not today"
     end   
end
```

When I call the method in my view, I always received "No today", even if the `now` date and `next_appointment_date` are equals.

Comment: Are you sure that `next_appointment_date` is what you think it is? Add a `puts now` and `puts next_appointment_date` in there and see what values they are at runtime.

Comment: did you try to run #to_date on next_appointment_date in comparison? It is possible that they are of different class types

Comment: Thank you!, only I needed to re-format the next_appointment_date with utc.to_date method, like this:

next_appointment_date.utc.to_date

Then, comparing dates was perfect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a helper method in rails `DateTime#today?`
You could rewrite your method to:

```
def compare_dates
  if next_appointment_date.today? 
    "Today"
  else
    "Not today"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!, this works perfect! Also works with next_appointment_date.utc.to_date and then compare